# Swift : Check if image url has changed

Tags: swift, imageview, compare, equatable

I have a view which shows a chosen object (Product), from a collectionView and gives the user the possibility to make changes to that product. Before going back to the collectionViewController I want to check if there has been any changes done and ask the user if they want to save or not.

The Product contains a url?.absoluteString for the imageView. I do the comparison with Equatable,

```
if product1 != product2 { 
   ask if save or not 
}
```

The biggest issue is that when I create the absolutString, the image is uploaded to Firebase and that takes unnecessary time. And if I don't want to save the changes, it's too late because I have already changed the image in firebase.

```
// getting the url String

func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?) -> ()) {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("myImage.jpeg")
        let imageData = imageHolder.imageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("success")
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    completion(url!)
                })
            } else {
                print("error in save image")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }


// comparing the two objects

func checkEditedProduct() -> Bool {

        var productsAreSame = true

        uploadImage(imageHolder.imageView.image!) { (url) in
            let product = Product(name: self.productName.text.text!,
                                  barCode: self.productGANText.text!,
                                  sellPrice: Int(self.productPrice.text.text!) ?? 0,
                                  buyPrice: Int(self.productWorth.text.text!) ?? 0,
                                  picture: url?.absoluteString,
                                  numberOfItemsInStock: Int(self.productInStock.text.text!) ?? 0,
                                  stockKeepingUnit: self.productSKU.text.text)
            self.compareProduct.append(product)
        }

        if compareProduct.count == 2 {
            if compareProduct[0] != compareProduct[1] {
                productsAreSame = false
            }
        }

        return productsAreSame
    }
```

I wan't to know if there is a way to check if the image in the imageView has been tampered with or not without having to make any calls to firebase database or storage

Comment: How to change image from detail? Image picker?

Comment: @Vicaren There are two ways to set the image, one is with imagepicker (camera or album) and the other is with 5 images from assets file, sort of "default" images if you don't want to take your own

Comment: I think save user image path folder in device disk and read from disk for any changes. If image has been changed you can upload to firebase